# List of dictConfig configuration options for Python logging handlers?

Tags: python, logging

Where can I find a list of configuration options for Python's logging handlers? For example, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) say that the TimedRotatingFileHandler takes a "when" argument. How can this be defined using dictConfig?

Like this?:

```
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'formatter':'default',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'when': 'midnight',
          ....
    },
},
```

If so, do all the option names for dictConfig correcpond exactly to the code examples on the docs? Just wondering, since I have yet to find a separate page listing the option names for use with dictConfig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is for the key names in the configuration dict to be the same as the named args in the corresponding call to construct the handler (or formatter, or filter). This will then work with externally defined handlers, too. Given a dict `config` which holds the configuration of an object (like a handler), the configuration code does the equivalent of

```
constructor = config['class'] # or '()' for a custom object being configured
kwargs = dict([(k, config[k]) for k in config if valid_ident(k)])
obj = constructor(**kwargs)
```

to get the configured object. Any keys that are not valid identifiers are ignored. In the case of handlers, `level,`formatter`and`filters` are also ignored in the constructor call, as they have special significance in the logging configuration.